# Output do maior valor da matriz saindo incorreto

Tags: c, matriz

O código não imprime o maior valor da matriz informada pelo usuário

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main(void){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int n, m, o=0, posic, posic1;
    int matriz[n][m];
    int  lin, col, maior=0, x=0;


    printf("Para usar o programa, digite as dimensões da matriz desejada.\n");
    printf("Digite a dimensão das linhas: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);

    printf("Digite a dimensão das colunas: ");
    scanf("%i", &m);


    printf("Agora digite os elementos dessa matriz %ix%i: \n", n, m);
    for(lin=0;lin<n;lin++){
        for(col=0;col<m;col++){
            scanf("%i", &matriz[n][m]);

        }
    }



    for(lin=0;lin<n;lin++){
        for(col=0;col<m;col++){
            if(maior < matriz[lin][col]){
                maior = matriz[lin][col];

            }
        }
        printf("O maior elemento da linha %i é: %i\t", 1+o,  maior);
        printf("Ele está localizado na coluna %i!\n", lin);
        o++;
    }
}
```

Eu depurei o programa e na primeira vez que passa pelo 'for' a variável 'maior' fica com "lixo na memória" fazendo assim o comando 'if' se tornar inútil nos outros loops.

```
for(lin=0;lin<n;lin++){
            for(col=0;col<m;col++){
                if(maior < matriz[lin][col]){
                    maior = matriz[lin][col];
```

Output
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Era para informar o valor de 6 na primeira linha e o valor de 8 na segunda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu primeiro problema é que você está declarando a matriz antes de definir seu tamanho. Declare ela depois de definir os valores de `n` e `m`, `int matriz[n][m]`. Seu segundo problema está no laço for que você adiciona os valores, você deve adicionar os valores assim:

```
scanf("%d", &matriz[lin][col]);
```

Por último você tem que zerar o valor de `maior` no fim desse laço, para que não ocorra um bug na comparação com outras linhas e você deve criar uma variável para guardar o valor da coluna com o maior valor:

```
 for(lin=0;lin<n;lin++){
    for(col=0;col<m;col++){
        if(maior < matriz[lin][col]){
            maior = matriz[lin][col];
            pos = col // adicione para guardar a coluna com o maior valor
        }
    }
    printf("O maior elemento da linha %i é: %i\t", 1+o,  maior);
    printf("Ele está localizado na coluna %i!\n", pos);// aqui você usa a variavél pos
    o++;
    maior = 0; // adicione esta linha
}
```